# Failed to import package with error: Couldn't decompress package

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been trying to import the asset called Winter Forest Envoriment and everytime I click import it gives me the error "Failed to import package with error: Couldn't decompress package
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:,ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)"

I've stumpled across some other threads were they imported outside the unity package manager, and not directly from the package manager. Other assets works like a charm except this one, and since there aren't a remove button in the package manager anymore I can't delete and try again.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Possible that the Unity versions are just too different? I had this issue quite a time ago when I tried importing a unitypackge (not via the Package Manager) via script for a Jenkins build process .. it always worked and some day suddenly stopped with a new Unity version until I exported a new unitypackge file (with the exact same content - a single build script) from this newer version. So, wherever you get your asset file from .. are you sure it is supported by the Unity version your are using?

Comment: Well I bought it from the asset store so I was expecting it would work, perhabs I need to change the version. I'm currently using 2020.1.3f1 which actually isn't the latest official released version.

Comment: Could you show a link to that asset? I ment it the other way round: Maybe the asset is only supported by an older Unity version and the one you use is too new. In general I would stick to the LTS releases except you really need the absolutely newest features. This would be `2019.4.11` currently

Comment: I downgraded to 2019.4.11 and it didn't make a difference, I guess I'll just have to reinstall Unity since it's my only option left.

Answer (score 6):

Try deleting and re-downloading. You'll likely find it under:

```
%AppData%\Roaming\Unity\Asset Store-5.x
```

Comment: Yes, once you have freed up some space on all drives, then delete the folder from this directory.  Then refresh and re-download in the package manager.  Worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered this issue before when I didn't have enough disk space on my computer for Unity to decompress the package. So, if you haven't done so yet, check that you have enough storage.

Comment: Then when enought space is available, delete the previous package folder from %AppData%\Roaming\Unity\Asset Store-5.x  and re-download as mentioned by  @dude-with-same-issue below

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have the required space and the project folder location in a writable directory

Answer (score 0):

use winrar to open the unitypackage, it will display a file within it, extract that file and import it as custom package, note: when you try to import the extracted file change file type from unity package to all in the import select window

Comment: I don't see in the question where OP stated that his asset would be packed as Zip or Rar file ... usually assets are provided as `.unitypackage` files which don't require any third party extraction tool

Answer (score 0):

Unity does not let you import the assets while Unity is in the PLAY mode (i.e. while you play the game inside Unity). That is the reason you get that error.

Here is the solution:

First, you need to stop your game play in Unity. Then, you can download and import the asset successfully in Unity.

Comment: That isn't the only reason why Unity might fail to decompress a package, I am currently having this problem with a NEW project that has not yet even entered play mode, I can be certain that Unity does not think I am in play mode

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the space on the drive:

   %AppData%\Roaming\Unity\Asset Store-5.x

   which is under your main user directory on the system drive
   NOT necessarily the same drive where Unity is installed.
2. Once there is enough space and write permission on this drive, go in
   and Delete the folder in there containing the Asset you were trying to
   install.  (eg Yughes Free Ground Materials)
3. Go back to the package manager and refresh the list of assets, which should make the Download button reappear.
4. Redownload the package and import successfully.

This step by step is basically a summary of the correct information from the above answers.